# If my credit card payment is due in 3 days time, will anything I order today have to be paid by then too?

Tags: united-states, credit-card

My credit card has a balance of $600 due on the 12th every month (I'm looking to get this date moved to later on in the month, how do I do that?). I'd like to make a $1000 purchase on my card in the coming days, but I don't know if I'll have to pay that $1000 off by the 12th too, or if I can put that off until the 12th of September.

I've been paying off my card in full every month and never had a balance past the due-date, but it seems a bit silly to me if you're not allowed to carry any debt for at least 30 days because you'd have to pay off charges made on the 10th or 11th by the 12th of the same month.

### Update

I contacted my Credit Union and got an answer:

1. The Credit Card payment due date is the 12th of every month, and that applies to all of their customers. This date cannot be changed.
2. The payment due date has a grace-period of 10 days. Using the grace period has no attached penalty nor does it affect one's credit-rating. I asked if there was any reason not to use the grace period and they told me "no".
3. Charges made to the card between the 1st and 31st of Month 1 will require payment by the 12th of Month 2. Charges made to the card between the 1st and 31st of Month 2 will not require payment until the 12th of Month 3, not Month 2.

So that clears that up then :)

Comment: Just to check: where are you located geographically?

Comment: @JohnBensin I live in Seattle, WA. I bank with a credit union specialising in technology company employees.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to add a country tag to your question because money.SE is an international site and the answer can vary from country to country.

Comment: This question is a warning sign.  If you're cutting things that close, ask yourself if you really *need* to spend that money.  If you wait a month, you'll have the money in hand and this wouldn't even be a concern.

Comment: That ten-day grace period after the statement due date sounds completely bogus to me.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I wonder if it's different for credit unions? The Credit CARD Act mandates a minimum grace period of 21 days, so unless there are details missing, I don't see how they get around that.

Comment: @JohnBensin There are two different dates: the _statement_ date and the _due date_ which must differ by at least 21 days (in the US). So what is this grace period of 10 days after the due date? Is it that the credit union will accept payments for up to ten days after the due date but will not report the payment as late to TransUnion, Equifax, etc? Will interest be charged for days of late payment? Credit-card companies usually charge interest from the date of charge for future purchases if the statement balance is not paid in full by the due date. Does this apply to credit-union cards too?

Comment: @DilipSarwate good question - I'll ask them and post an update.

Comment: What is the difference beteween due day and due date? I understand that due day it is the day of every month your payment is due and due date is the effective date that it should be paid. E.G. my credit card due day is every 12th of each month but if it falls on a Saturday the due date will be on the 14th. Is that right? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're in the US - then **no.** You'll owe payment on your purchase on your next statement due date (September 12th), not your current due date (August 12th). In other countries, your closing date and due date may be the same, in which case you're required to make a payment on the same day your statement is posted.

Your credit card has two different dates that you need to know:

1. **Closing date** - The date your statement for the current period is posted.
2. **Due date** - The date your payment is due.

After your statement is posted on the closing date, you usually have a [**grace period**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_card#Grace_period) of at least [21 days](http://creditcardforum.com/blog/credit-card-grace-period/) (since the passage of the [Credit CARD Act of 2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_CARD_Act_of_2009)) before you're required to make at least the minimum payment on the statement's balance and before interest begins accruing on your balance. If you make a purchase *after* the closing date but *before* the due date, this purchase will be recorded on the statement for the *next* period.

In your case, your due date is August 12th. Your closing date is probably several weeks before that. Let's say it's July 20th. If you make a purchase anytime between July 20th and August 20th, this purchase will be recorded on your next statement, which will post on August 20th. Your payment for that purchase is due on September 12th, the due date for that period.

I'm assuming that you're paying in full each period (as you indicated in your question), because if you don't, then obviously, portions of your balances from previous statements will appear on your next statement(s) because you haven't paid them off in full yet. For some credit cards, the grace period only applies to the balance from the current period, so you might still accrue interest on balances from previous periods every day that you don't make a payment.

---

Note that your *balance* before you make a payment may include the balance of your last statement and the balance of your purchases after the statement is posted, but if you select the option to pay in full, the amount you pay will be the balance of your last statement, not the total current balance on your card. In general, it's the balance when your statement is posted that matters.

> I'm looking to get this date moved to later on in the month, how do I do that?

This varies depending on your credit card provider, but it's probably somewhere in the online interface, or you could call their customer service and ask them to change the date for you. The change may not take place immediately, to prevent you from pushing back your payment for the current period, but it will probably take effect within a few cycles. Some credit card companies won't let you change this date during your card's [anniversary period](http://help.barclaycard.co.uk/brochure/credit_cards/anniversary-period), so you may need to wait until the next period to change it.

Comment: I have never had a one week grace period, it has always been in the range of 21-25 days. For example pay on the 8th of August, then it closes on the 14th of August to be due on the 8th of September.

Comment: John, your answer is good for the US (and other places maybe), but not for everywhere. I have used foreign-issued cards that have zero grace period, and the payment is due when the statement closes. In the country I lived then - that's the standard way of doing things.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Good point, that's how my card is too. I tried to give a really simple example; do you think I should change it, or is my small added note enough for the time being?

Comment: @littleadv Thanks for the edit; I added your comment into my answer too. Out of curiosity, what countries do you know of that don't have a grace period?

Comment: @john Israel in my case, I'm sure there are more.

Comment: The statement date and due date have a required minimum time span, I believe about two weeks, to allow for mail transit time. My most used card statement is cut on the 15th and due on the 10th of the next month.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I didn't realize that was actually a law, but the reasoning makes sense. I updated my example to use more realistic dates, as well as a reference to the law itself (the Credit CARD Act of 2009).

Comment: Imagine if your card bill came and was due a day later. This was a case of the law implementing what should be common sense.